# Animate display:none to display:inline

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to make a webpage with two different sets of text (Text A and Text B), which are different lengths, and are not in order by A/B (i.e. There is Text A before and After Text B).

On the top, there are three buttons: `Show All`, `Text A`, and `Text B`.

When `Show All` is clicked, all text is shown, when `Text A` is clicked, only Text A text is shown and Text B text is hidden, etc.

I want to animate the change of text (with a fade animation).
Is there an easy way of doing this?

```js
function select(name) {
  var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  var elems = navbar.getElementsByTagName("li");

  var classes = [];

  for (x = 0; x < elems.length; x++) {
    var obj = elems[x].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    obj.className = elems[x].id !== name ? "nav" : "navsel";
    classes[x] = elems[x].id;
  }

  for (n = 0; n < classes.length; n++) {
    var allelems = document.getElementsByClassName(classes[n]);
    for (x = 0; x < allelems.length; x++) {
      var s = allelems[x].className;
      if (s.search(name) >= 0 || name === "all") {
        s = s.replace(" hide", "");
      } else if (s.search("hide") < 0) {
        s += " hide";
      }
      allelems[x].className = s;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li.nav {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
a.nav,
a:visited.nav {
  display: table-cell;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #800000;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a.navsel,
a:visited.navsel {
  display: table-cell;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #C00000;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a:hover.nav,
a:active.nav {
  background-color: #A00000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
a:hover.navsel,
a:active.navsel {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav" id="navbar">
  <li class="nav" id="all">
    <a class="navsel" onclick="select('all');">Show All</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav" id="texta">
    <a class="nav" onclick="select('texta');">Text A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav" id="textb">
    <a class="nav" onclick="select('textb');">Text B</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<br />
<br />
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<h2 class="texta">Text A</h2>
<p class="texta">We the people of the United States, in order to form a more perfect union, establish justice, insure domestic tranquility, provide for the common defense, promote the general welfare, and secure the blessings of liberty to ourselves and our posterity,
  do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of America.</p>
<h2 class="textb">Text B</h2>
<p class="textb">
  We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness.
  <br />That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed,
  <br />That whenever any Form of Government becomes destructive of these ends, it is the Right of the People to alter or to abolish it, and to institute new Government, laying its foundation on such principles and organizing its powers in such form, as to
  them shall seem most likely to effect their Safety and Happiness. Prudence, indeed, will dictate that Governments long established should not be changed for light and transient causes; and accordingly all experience hath shewn, that mankind are more
  disposed to suffer, while evils are sufferable, than to right themselves by abolishing the forms to which they are accustomed. But when a long train of abuses and usurpations, pursuing invariably the same Object evinces a design to reduce them under
  absolute Despotism, it is their right, it is their duty, to throw off such Government, and to provide new Guards for their future security.
  <br />Such has been the patient sufferance of these Colonies; and such is now the necessity which constrains them to alter their former Systems of Government. The history of the present King of Great Britain is a history of repeated injuries and usurpations,
  all having in direct object the establishment of an absolute Tyranny over these States.
</p>
<h1>More Text</h1>
<h2 class="texta">Text A</h2>
<p class="texta">Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.</p>
<h2 class="textb">Text B</h2>
<p class="textb">Live as if you were to die tomorrow. Learn as if you were to live forever.</p>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a plain vanilla JavaScript answer or are you open to using a library like jQuery?

Comment: @j08691 I have never used jQuery, and would prefer not to have to figure out how to use it (I would prefer a plain JS answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that doesn't require any librarys such as Jquery.

Using `setTimeout` we're able to give the element a style of `display:none` only after it fades out.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MCVE</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul.nav {
                list-style-type:none;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                position:fixed;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                background:#ffffff;
                width:100%;
                height:30px;
                text-align:center;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
            li.nav {
                float:left;
                width:33.3333%;
                height:100%;
                display:table;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            a.nav, a:visited.nav {
                display:table-cell;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#ffffff;
                background-color:#800000;
                padding:4px;
                text-decoration:none;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
            a.navsel, a:visited.navsel {
                display:table-cell;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#ffffff;
                background-color:#C00000;
                padding:4px;
                text-decoration:none;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
            a:hover.nav, a:active.nav {
                background-color:#A00000;
                color:#ffffff;
            }
            a:hover.navsel, a:active.navsel {
                color:#ffffff;
            }

            .hide {
                opacity:0;
            }
          
            .noDisplay{
              display:none;
            }
          
            p, h2{
                transition: 
                opacity 1s ease
            }
          
            .show{
              animation-name: fadeIn; 
              animation-duration: 2s; 
              animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }


            @keyframes fadeIn {
                0% { 
                 opacity:0;
                  }
                100% { 
                  opacity:1;
                  }
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function select( element ){
              if( element.parentElement.id == 'texta' ){
                 document.getElementById( 'all' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.remove( 'navsel' );
                 document.getElementById( 'all' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.add( 'nav' );
                
                 document.getElementById( 'textb' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.remove( 'navsel' );
                 document.getElementById( 'textb' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.add( 'nav' );
                
                 document.getElementById( 'texta' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.add( 'navsel' );
                       
                 element.classList.add( 'navsel' );
                 var everyElement = document.getElementsByClassName( 'textb' );
                 for( var i = 0; i < everyElement.length; i++ ){
                   everyElement[ i ].classList.add( 'hide' );
                 }
                 removeElement = setTimeout( removeNowA, 900 );    
              }
              else if( element.parentElement.id == 'textb' ){
                 document.getElementById( 'all' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.remove( 'navsel' );
                 document.getElementById( 'all' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.add( 'nav' );
                
                 document.getElementById( 'texta' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.remove( 'navsel' );
                 document.getElementById( 'texta' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.add( 'nav' );
                
                 document.getElementById( 'textb' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.add( 'navsel' );
                
                 var everyElement = document.getElementsByClassName( 'texta' );
                 for( var i = 0; i < everyElement.length; i++ ){
                   everyElement[ i ].classList.add( 'hide' );
                 }
                 removeElement = setTimeout( removeNowB, 900 );    
              }
              else if( element.parentElement.id == 'all' ){
                 document.getElementById( 'texta' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.remove( 'navsel' );
                 document.getElementById( 'texta' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.add( 'nav' );
                
                 document.getElementById( 'textb' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.remove( 'navsel' );
                 document.getElementById( 'textb' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.add( 'nav' );
                
                 document.getElementById( 'all' ).childNodes[ 1 ].classList.add( 'navsel' );
                
                 var everyElement = document.getElementsByClassName( 'textb' );
                 for( var i = 0; i < everyElement.length; i++ ){
                   everyElement[ i ].classList.remove( 'noDisplay' );

                 }
                var everyElement = document.getElementsByClassName( 'texta' );
                 for( var i = 0; i < everyElement.length; i++ ){
                   everyElement[ i ].classList.remove( 'noDisplay' );

                 }
                
                 fadeIn();
              }
            }
          function removeNowA(){
            var everyElement = document.getElementsByClassName( 'textb' );
            for( var i = 0; i < everyElement.length; i++ ){
              everyElement[ i ].classList.add( 'noDisplay' );
            }
          }
          function removeNowB(){
            var everyElement = document.getElementsByClassName( 'texta' );
            for( var i = 0; i < everyElement.length; i++ ){
              everyElement[ i ].classList.add( 'noDisplay' );
            }
          }
          
          function fadeIn(){
            var everyElement = document.getElementsByClassName( 'textb' );
            for( var i = 0; i < everyElement.length; i++ ){
              everyElement[ i ].classList.add( 'show' );

            }
            var everyElement = document.getElementsByClassName( 'texta' );
            for( var i = 0; i < everyElement.length; i++ ){
            everyElement[ i ].classList.add( 'show' );

             }

          }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="nav" id="navbar">
            <li class="nav" id="all">
                <a class="navsel" onclick="select( this );">Show All</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav" id="texta">
                <a class="nav" onclick="select( this );">Text A</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav" id="textb">
                <a class="nav" onclick="select( this );">Text B</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br /><br />
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <h2 class="texta">Text A</h2>
        <p class="texta">We the people of the United States, in order to form a more perfect union, establish justice, insure domestic tranquility, provide for the common defense, promote the general welfare, and secure the blessings of liberty to ourselves and our posterity, do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of America.</p>
        <h2 class="textb">Text B</h2>
        <p class="textb">
            We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness.
            <br />That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed,
            <br />That whenever any Form of Government becomes destructive of these ends, it is the Right of the People to alter or to abolish it, and to institute new Government, laying its foundation on such principles and organizing its powers in such form, as to them shall seem most likely to effect their Safety and Happiness. Prudence, indeed, will dictate that Governments long established should not be changed for light and transient causes; and accordingly all experience hath shewn, that mankind are more disposed to suffer, while evils are sufferable, than to right themselves by abolishing the forms to which they are accustomed. But when a long train of abuses and usurpations, pursuing invariably the same Object evinces a design to reduce them under absolute Despotism, it is their right, it is their duty, to throw off such Government, and to provide new Guards for their future security.
            <br />Such has been the patient sufferance of these Colonies; and such is now the necessity which constrains them to alter their former Systems of Government. The history of the present King of Great Britain is a history of repeated injuries and usurpations, all having in direct object the establishment of an absolute Tyranny over these States.
        </p>
        <h1>More Text</h1>
        <h2 class="texta">Text A</h2>
        <p class="texta">Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.</p>
        <h2 class="textb">Text B</h2>
        <p class="textb">Live as if you were to die tomorrow. Learn as if you were to live forever.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Run the code snippet: The text disappears, but doesn't come back.

Comment: @ricky3350 try again, I just fixed it.

Comment: Better... It needs to switch from A to B, and animate when you click Show All

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on it. This part is a little tricky given the code we have.

Comment: Works fairly well now. Keep in mind this a very poorly coded version I threw together quickly just to show you the basics of how you might do this. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes... It's better, and I think I can get somewhere with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a quick script for you, hope it will help you further.

```css
.content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .75s ease-in-out;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .75s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="article-a" onclick="document.getElementById('contentA').className = 'show';">Text A</button>
<button class="article-b" onclick="document.getElementById('contentB').className = 'show';">Text B</button>
<button class="article-all" onclick="document.getElementById('contentA').className = 'show';document.getElementById('contentB').className = 'show';">All Text</button>

<div id="contentA" class="content">First part</div>
<div id="contentB" class="content">Second Part</div>
```

I believe it's better to use `opacity` for the transition, after opacity set to 1, you could hide the element.

Comment: How exactly would I do this?

Comment: What about going from A to B?

Comment: Remove the classname show from ContentA, Add classname show to ContentB

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would handle this by attaching the fadein and fadeout JQuery method to each class of text whenever it is clicked. You can do this by defining them in a simple Javascript that fades one class in and the other out and vice versa

```
$("#texta").click(function(){
  //Show texta and hide textb
  $("#texta").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#textb").fadeOut("slow");
});

$("#textb").click(function(){
  //Show textb and hide texta
  $("#textb").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#texta").fadeOut("slow");
});

$("#all").click(function(){
  //Show texta and hide textb
  $("#texta").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#textb").fadeIn("slow");
});
```